# search and replace all the empty string in ObservableCollection using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I have an observable collection as below:

```
public ObservableCollection<TestModel> TestList
{
    get { return m_TestList; }
}
```

TestModel class contains following properties:

```
public string TestType { get; set; }
public string TestDetails { get; set; }
```

I am looking for:
Search all occurences of the property "TestDetails" in the collection "TestList" for the empty or null string and replace with the string "No Data Available"

Please suggest with a code snippet.Preferably using LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Linq is about querying not about updating.  You could update using a select as a side-effect but I wouldn't recommend it.

```
// Return back the objects that have empty TestDetails
foreach (var testmodel in TestList.Where(t => String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.TestDetails)))
{
    //update the object
    testmodel.TestDetails = "No Data Available";
}
```